# How do I run my exe in the Visual Studio debugger at an arbitrary location on my PC?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I have a program (32-bit .exe written in C++) that runs fine in the Debug directory of my project development tree but when I move it to another folder on my PC it crashes.   I want to run it in the debugger from the new location to debug it.    How do I start my .exe in the debugger at some arbitrary location on my PC?

I'm running Visual Studio 2013.

I want to set a breakpoint at the first executable line and step from there, just like I would if it was in the normal Debug path.

Comment: Simply use Project > Properties > Debug tab > Start external program.  This is going to happen on your user's machine as well, now without a debugger, writing an event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException is never really optional.

Comment: @HansPassant: what's wrong letting WER handle the crash? IMHO, unhandled exception handlers never work as well as letting Windows do the job.

Comment: If it worked well then he of course wouldn't have asked this question.  Not everybody is a minidump jockey, least of all the client.

Comment: I want to set a breakpoint at the first executable line and step from there, just like I would if it was in the normal Debug path.  I've added an edit to my question to clarify this.

Comment: @HansPassant: I don't see such a tab (VS 2013)  There's something called "Debugging" and in that there's Command set to $(TargetPath) and WorkingDirectory set to $(ProjectDir).    Do those have anything to do with where it looks?

Comment: Hmm, no, those are settings for a C++ project.  Nothing to do with C#.  You sound confused about the language you program in, pretty hard to get effective help.

Comment: Sorry my bad - you are correct that it's a C++ project -  I mostly work in C# and inherited this project from someone else so i wasn't thinking when I typed that.  I've fixed it.

Comment: at what point does it crash? at startup? if not you can always attach the debugger to the running .exe and take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could always add this somewhere in your app, which will open a prompt to attach a debugger when the app is run.

```
#if DEBUG
            if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                Debugger.Launch();
            Debugger.Break();
#endif
```

Comment: The user probably wouldn't appreciate this.   I just want to be able to say "Start Debugging" as normal, but Visual Studio should look in the new location instead of MyProject\Debug

Comment: Why would you give the debug version of the binary to users?

Comment: Are you saying there's no way to tell Visual Studio to look in a particular place for the .exe without modifying the source code?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013, go to project properties, select the *Debug* configuration and go to *Debugging*. Enter the command, command line arguments and working directory.

Here's a screenshot of how it looks like:

[image: C++ Debug Settings in VS2013]

Be sure to *not* move the PDBs. The EXE contains a reference to the PDBs and if the PDBs are not in the original place, Visual Studio cannot find them.

If you have already moved the PDBs, set up the symbol path accordingly in `Tools | Options | Debugging`.

The dialog looks like this:

[image: Visual Studio 2013 C++ Symbol Path]